# Profiling Google Cloud Dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

What would be the best way to profile a dataflow job if the scale does not permit doing so locally?
In the past, I tried using jstack to check what the Java threads are doing on the worker instances, but that doesn't seem to work for anymore.
Of course I can use stopwatches and log the measured timing data, but I was hoping maybe there is a better way.

*Update: The instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782719/jstack-and-other-tools-on-google-cloud-dataflow-vms/27785897#27785897) still seem to work, with the only difference that instead of installing java with `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`, I had to download it from Oracle's site.*

Thanks,
GB

Comment: Do you have any more details about why jstack stopped working for you? Is there a specific failure message or failure mode?

Comment: The error I see is that it can't find a HotSpot VM in the process I provided. Maybe I installed a slightly different version - e.g., OpenJDK vs Oracle or something like that.

Comment: Installing jstack worked, updated the question with info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, you can install `jstack` if you install the JDK.

We have a Github issue tracking the need for [user-code profiling](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/72) -- check there for progress.

Comment: This [Github issue update](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/72) includes some basic instructions for getting profiles without the need for `jstack`.